# How to open URL link in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, url

Hello I am developing a Swift application and I need to start an AudioFile from URL link.

```
let metadateObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if metadateObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {

        let BarcodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadateObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        qrCodeframeView?.frame = BarcodeObject.bounds

        if metadateObj.stringValue != nil  {

            Label.text = metadateObj.stringValue
```

Basically I have a QR code camera which should scan the QR code (link of the mp4 file) and save it as Label.text

Then I use this code :

```
let movieURL: NSURL? = NSURL ( string: "\(Label.text)")
        if let url = movieURL {
            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
     }
```

to start the player but it doesn`t play the mp4 file.

From the other hand if I replace the Label.text with the actual link:

```
 let movieURL: NSURL? = NSURL ( string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
        if let url = movieURL {
            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
     }
```

Here it works perfect: I am so confused I am sure that I am making everything correct because it is not the first time I am doing that. But in this case it is not working. Would you please be able to find my stupid mistake, I am frustrated!!!

Comment: What is the exact value of your Label.text?

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: Your update doesn't show the actual and exact value of Label.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
  OpenLabelButton.isHidden = false
            Label.isHidden = true
            captureSession?.stopRunning()

            label2 = Label.text!
```

And then

```
 let movieURL: NSURL? = NSURL ( string: "\(label2)")
            if let url = movieURL {
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Swift 3 you should use URL instead of NSURL. BTW Swift is a type inferred language. give it a try.

Comment: Why use `"\(label2)"` as the parameter instead of simply `label2`?